# Mikrotik IPV6 dhcp client

Tags: networking, ipv6, mikrotik

The DHCP client in my mikrotik router never obtains a ipv6 address or prefix, when connected to internet.  I understand I need a prefix, so the devices on my lan can get a valid external IP.

However when I connect my laptop everything works as expected?

Comment: Just asking for a prefix got me a reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured out I needed to only ask for a prefix, then setup a DHCP server, and add an ipv6 address.

This post on the mikrotik forum was pretty clear.

https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=101918&p=506310&hilit=dhcpv6#p506307